# Is it possible to use "SELECT * FROM MyFunction()" syntax in Oracle for Pipelined Functions?

Tags: oracle, pipelined-function

Is it possible to call an Oracle Pipelined Function without specifying TABLE( ) operator, like in the following example?

```
SELECT * FROM MyFunction()
```

I don't want to use the following, due to compatibility with SqlServer.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE( MyFunction() )
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try it? What happened when you did? What does the manual say about the `SELECT` statement syntax?

Comment: Short answer, no.  Longer answer, if your real function takes no arguments, as in your example, then you can create a view that queries the pipelined table function (using the `table` operator) and then query the view from your application without needing the `table` operator.  Of course, a pipelined table function that takes no arguments can almost always be written more efficiently in pure SQL.

Comment: A view would help you? `create view MyFunction as select * from TABLE(MyFunction())`; might not help in case parametrized calls..

Comment: I really need to pass parameters to MyFunction in my real scenario.

Answer (score 0):

First, table function is not a good idea in Oracle, since it loads all the data to the memory, and no indexes will be used in your query any more.

Second, table functions work totaly differerent in SQL Server  & Oracle,
My best suggestion is to use **dynamicSql**, the function will build sql string  and return it  and the main procedure will execute it, should work in oracle and sql server as well.

Comment: Functions that build a large collection and return it wil use a lot of memory.  But pipelined functions are different.  From [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/tuning.htm#LNPLS915): "A pipelined table function returns a row to its invoker immediately after processing that row and continues to process rows. Response time improves because the entire collection need not be constructed and returned to the server before the query can return a single result row. (Also, the function needs less memory, because the object cache need not materialize the entire collection.)"

Comment: @Jon Heller, In the end It still in the memory and not in the disc , from my own experience, changing the pipeline function to dynamic sql improved my queries performance in high percentages

Comment: @ElishevaWasserman, I need to use Table Valued Function, because we're porting an SqlServer .NET application with Entity Framework to Oracle. We can't change the model. The aim is to use TVF with Entity Framework.

Comment: Can you be more specific? 1. as  far as I know, stored function in oracle  are not supported by EF,2.  when you use entityframework, usually you don't have to worry about different provides